# Grails 2.4 filters don't seem to be working

Tags: grails

I have a Grails 2.4.4 app. In it I have the following controllers:

```
myapp/
    grails-app/
        controllers/
            fizzbuzz/
                FizzController.groovy
                BuzzController.groovy
                ... many others, etc.
```

I want to create [Grails Filters](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/guide/theWebLayer.html#filters) for some of these, so I create a `grails-app/conf/WidgetFilters.groovy` class:

```
class WidgetFilters {
    def filters = {
        fizzFilter(controller: 'fizz*', action: '*') {
            before = {
                println 'I intercepted a called to the Fizz Controller!'  
            }
        }  
        buzzFilter(controller: 'buzz*', action: '*') {
            before = {
                println 'I intercepted a called to the Buzz Controller!'  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I start my app up and go to any Fizz/Buzz actions, I do not see the `println`. I've also tried other logging statements (SLF4J) and put other code inside the `before` closure and am 100% convinced they are not executing. Have I done something obviously wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried to restart app + clean build?

I've copy-pasted your filters and mock controllers and they're working, [here](https://github.com/majkelo/GrailsFilterTest) is a code.

Please check out also this [properties](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v2/guide/urlProperties.html):

- apf.continueChainBefore SuccessfulAuthentication - whether to continue calling subsequent filters in the filter chain
- fii.observeOncePerRequest - If false allow checks to happen multiple times, for example when JSP forwards are being used and filter security is desired on each included fragment of the HTTP request

Comment: Thanks @majkelo (+1) - I am thinking more and more that this is a conflict with the security filters provided by the Grails Shiro plugin (please see my comment underneath Burt's answer)

Comment: Hey @majkelo, do you know if you're allowed to have multiple Filters classes? Or just one?

Comment: @smeeb you're allowed to have them more than one. I added to dev repo second filter for fizz and both are working.

Comment: Did you try to remove Shiro plugin and check if it's working? Maybe it's something else causing troubles.

Comment: I've added spring security properties which can be handful. Check them out.

Answer (score 1):

Move the class into `grails-app/conf`.

Comment: Ahh, so sorry @BurtBeckwith (+1) - this was a copy-paste error! It *is* under `grails-app/conf/` (please see my edits). Please note I am using a Grails plugin here ("`grails-myorg`"), which in turn uses the [Grails Shiro](https://grails.org/plugin/shiro) plugin and which generates SecurityFilters for me. I'm wondering if those security filters are somehow overwriting the `WidgetFilters` that I'm providing here. The problem is: `grails-myorg` is a reusable (organization-wide) plugin and it doesn't make sense to put `WidgetFilters` logic inside it!